# How do I export a model to .obj format?

Tags: export, obj

I use Blender to create my 3D models for my Android app that uses OpenGL ES. The default output format for a Wavefront file (.obj) is not compatible with my Wavefront file parser. How do I get Blender to output a Wavefront file that has the following elements:

- All Verticies and Faces (faces as triangles, not quads)
- Texture coordinates (UV Mapped)
- Preprocessed Normals

Comment: UVs are included in OBJ export, theres an option to triangulate and include normals in the export options.

Did you try these options?

This seems more like a bug report then a question since you are asking about existing features that apparently don't work in some situation.

Comment: @ideasman42 For someone who was trying to use Blender to make models for use in OpenGl or other platforms, the Wavefront file needs to have those exact properties otherwise it won't get parsed correctly. This question was intended to help people find those exact options in the export menu.

Comment: OBJ has been used with textures, materials, normals etc - for quite some time now. So if it fails you need to ask if a specific configuration is known to be supported. What 'exact properties' are you referring to? 

Also 'OpenGL or other platforms' us too vague - which software fails to read blenders OBJ's?

Comment: @ideasman42 read the question (I want to export my model into a .obj file with the following:) - those are the exact properties I am referring to. The point of this beta is to build a question base so that we have a bunch of good questions when the public beta starts. Even a really simple question can be considered a 'good' question.

Comment: The problem is you are not actually trying to solve anything here (an imagined problem or a real one). The options are clearly listed in the export menu - so any user who spends a few seconds to check will see what to do, I dont think this makes for quality Q&A.

(However Im glad you want http://blender.stackexchange.com to do well and are want to help out!)

Comment: @ideasman42 When I first used Blender to export to .obj it took me a long time to find that there is the tiny menu in the bottom left hand corner that you have to look at to change the output settings. I think that this question would be very helpful to someone who is a novice at using Blender.

Comment: @John It is acceptable to answer your own question; I see you've created several that you seem to know the answer to and are just posting to serve as a reference to others. Go ahead and answer them yourself, if you know the answer.

Comment: @John since you have admitted to having typed this knowing the answer and it being such a simple question, it's not ideal. Voted to close.

Comment: Might want to move this to meta.se for discussion if more comments get added.

Comment: @John, I think apart of the problem with your question is how you are phrasing it. If you actually had a problem, you would ask a much different question because you would be talking about something that doesn't work, and asking ways to make it work as you expect. This kind of question would be much more straightforward to answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you wanted to export a simple model such as:

[image]

as a .obj file that is compatible with OpenGL or another 3D graphics platform then all you do is go to export:

[image]

Look for the export options in the toolbar in the bottom left corner. This will allow you to choose the specifications for the output file:

[image]

The options I am using above are compatible with OpenGL ES, you may have to adjust your properties accordingly. This type of export will produce a .obj file (geometry file) and a .mtl file (materials and textures file).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that the default options would break my renderer.

Comment: Sorry, "bottom left" didn't help me. This is what I'm looking at RN. Where do i find the "export obj" settings ? https://i.imgur.com/xd3mgdI.png