# How to remove the default cube?

Tags: customization, scene

How do you remove the default cube that appears in the scene upon opening the software? I wish to start with a blank scene when opening Blender.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [**How to change Blender's default startup settings?**](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/186/199)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of 'How do i delete an object?' because this question and answer intends to include the process of saving it as the startup file. Deleting the cube is not as important but it's included. While the answer is accomplished in 'How to change Blender's default startup settings?', that answer differs because this question/answer is intended for less advanced users who wish to accomplish this exact task of removing the default cube and they may not know to search for changing the default startup settings.

Comment: IMHO this is borderline anyway, see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121/599), but I think it is a duplicate of [How to change Blender's default startup settings?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/186/199). That answer makes it clear that setting the startup.blend sets the scene as a startup, users should be able to figure out that they want to delete the cube. (This is a pretty localized case anyway) If you think that the [answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187/599) might not be understood by new users, you can always edit it. Voted to close.

Comment: This is an obvious case of hat farming. Please stop.

Comment: @iKlsR hmm, but what is hat farming?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Delete the cube:**
Starting with the unchanged default scene, select the cube (<kbd>RMB</kbd> click on the cube) then hit <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>DELETE</kbd> and <kbd>RMB</kbd> click the following popup. You may also repeat this step on the camera and light if you wish to start with a completely blank scene.

**Save the startup file:**
Click **File** > **Defaults** > **Save Startup File** (formerly *File > Save Startup File*) or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> and click to confirm. The scene is now saved as the default startup scene and you no longer have the default cube!

Comment: there is no save startup file