# How to generate texture image for home interior and how to use it in OpenGL ES?

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I designed a home interior and it includes wooden floor also. I used the UV/Image Editor to generate images to draw home interior in Open GLES but I failed to generate the image.

Another problem is that the Texture Coordinate array is not complete, that means many numbers of the coordinates are not available in the array it only shows comma separated blank spaces(using [obj2opengl.pl](https://github.com/HBehrens/obj2opengl/blob/master/obj2opengl.pl) to generate the array). I added an example image, I have to generate images like this.
[image]

Comment: Did you enable the options for exporting UVs described here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121/how-do-i-export-a-model-to-obj-format ?

Comment: yes have enabled all these options.my file having this problem. 
float Hall33TexCoords [] = {
  // f 2/1/1 4/2/1 3/3/1
  0.983474, 0.671719,
  0.122201, 0.240328,
  0.020922, 0.302471,
// f 1102/1101/276 1104/1102/276 1103/1103/276
  0.983474, 0.671719,
  0.122201, 0.240328,
  0.020922, 0.302471,
  // f 1101/1104/276 1102/1101/276 1103/1103/276
  0.882195, 0.733862,
  0.983474, 0.671719,
  0.020922, 0.302471,
  // f 1105//277 1106//277 1108//277
  , ,
  , ,
  , ,
  // f 1107//278 1108//278 1110//278
  , ,
  , ,
  , ,
}

Comment: some coordinates are blank spaces with comma

Comment: Could you add a part of the .obj file? Just to see Blender export is correct, when the obj2opengl script omits the values it would be off-topic here.

Comment: yes, i can but which part i have to add .obj file is too big.

Comment: You could upload the blend here: pasteall.org/blend/ or look into the file and post the part which coresponds to the snippet from your comment above.

Comment: I uploaded .blend on http://pasteall.org/blend/29990 .
i textured only floor, not walls and ceiling, so is this the reason for uncompleted TexCoords array?

Answer (score 1):

Blender exports the .obj file correctly I can't see a reason why empty values ",,,," are written in the converted file.

```
mtllib Musium.mtl
o Plane.275_Plane.229
v 138.827621 -14.357000 -71.175812
v 145.607269 -14.357000 -71.175812
v 138.827621 -14.357000 -123.266418
v 145.607269 -14.357000 -123.266418
vt 0.882195 0.266138
vt 0.983474 0.328281
vt 0.122201 0.759672
vt 0.020922 0.697529
```

It seems to be a bug/issue in the obj2opengl.pl converter possible it expects optional values which do not occur and therefore it writes empty values (between the commas).

I would recommend to write your own exporter, to get started you could use the code I posted here: [How do we access Vert, Norm and UV data then print to a text file using Blender/Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6403/how-do-we-access-vert-norm-and-uv-data-then-print-to-a-text-file-using-blender/6431#6431)

Comment: Thanks, but how can get final image for complete designed object, like example image which added in question. I am beginner and really i don't know how to this.

Comment: This can be done by texture painting or cloning (e.g. images) into a single texture this should be another question (needs space to explain).

Comment: Hello sir, I solve the problem of blank spaces, Thanks for your support.