# Exported model has no illumination when opened on other app.

Tags: materials, light, file-format

I am really new to 3D modelling and Blender. I found some ripped files and one of the models has an .obj and .mtl file. When I open it in Blender, both are loaded as usual, but when I export the model I don't see the illumination. I'm using Noesis to view the models.

I tried exporting as .dae, .fbx, and .obj, and I tried putting all the files from the model into one folder.

Am I missing something in the settings? Please let me know what other info you might need to help me figure this out!

Comment: Illumination is generally not consistent between different 3d software because each has their own approach to rendering light. Mostly you can just export and import light type, position and orientation but how it looks is up to the software you use.

Comment: Ohh, Would it help if I added links to the files for someone to help me illuminate it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy4txtrz1hyqciu/w_ri011.zip?dl=0

Comment: The point is if you want the illumination to work in software X you need to set up illumination in software X. This question is likely more about noesis.

Comment: So like a plugin? I think I heard someone made a plugin to go with these ripped models, i just havent been able to find it yet

Comment: No, not a plugin. Can you add screenshots of what it looks like in Blender, and what it looks like in Noesis?

Answer (score 2):

"Illumination" information is generally not transferred with a model.

In Blender, you're likely seeing the textures (images used like decals on the surface of the model), but the "lighting" won't be stored with the model.

What you might be experiencing is that the textures aren't being saved with the model, so when you open it with Noesis, it's just black or gray. Textures can be saved with the model, but you will have to tell Blender to do that. OBJ is really your best option, at this point. It will store basic model and texture information, and is very widely supported. You can make sure that it is exporting what you want by checking these settings ("Write Materials" is the important detail, here):

[image]

[This other answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121/how-do-i-export-a-model-to-obj-format) has a good set of instructions for how to export a Blender model as an OBJ. It'd be worth your time.

It also sounds like you still have a lot to learn. It'd be worth your time to watch every tutorial that BlenderGuru has, or at least every modeling tutorial. Covering all the basics will make the learning process easier.