# Can you export separate layers as .obj?

Tags: modeling

Can you export a layer as a obj?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121/how-do-i-export-a-model-to-obj-format/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, so I don't know if my answer is relevant, but here goes.

You could

1. save your file
2. make sure everything in every layer is deselected
3. Display only the layer you want to export
4. Select everything in it
5. With Shift held down click on all the other layers to display them too.
6. Invert the selection, with Control I, and press delete
7. Export the file normally. It only has the objects in that layer left.

Edit:

To answer your question in the comments - Select Only option is found in the left column of the page you're on after you click on Export as Wavefront Obj file.

[image]

Comment: Instead of deleting you could export the obj with Selection Only option checked with all objects on the layer selected.

Comment: Where do you find the selection only option?

Comment: See the edit with a picture I just put at the end of my answer to answer your question to Mr Zak.